# Proper way of partitioning a secondary hard drive for ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

Since I have two hard drives (C and D) and my D hard drive has a lot more unused space, I want to partition it so I can put ubuntu on it.  There are two main concerns I have.  The first is if I will still be able to put stuff on the unused space (the partition without ubuntu) of the D drive from windows.  The second is if I can just put the grub bootloader on the D drive, that way windows will automatically load unless I intentionally boot from D.  This seems doable from the little bit of research I've done but I want to take the proper precautionary steps.  I'm also a bit unsure of how the file systems will work (NTFS vs ext4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take help of this link [dual boot windows and ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) if you want to perform every step with utmost caution. It will also guide you on the partitioning `Windows` OS the right way.

Once you are done installing Ubuntu, perform the following steps to setup your grub menu:

- Boot into `Windows` OS
- Combine `Windows` + `r` together and type `cmd` to open command prompt.
- Type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit `enter` key

P.S - You do not need to have admin rights on command prompt before you perform the above action.

Comment: I'm assuming the instructions on that link are the same for doing it on a primary and secondary hard drive right?  But also doesnt the bcedit command you posted make grub always the default bootloader?  I was wondering if there was a way to have grub only on the secondary drive, that way my PC will normally boot with windows unless I choose which drive to boot from.  Hopefully what I'm asking makes sense.

Comment: The process remains the same brother irrespective of the hard drive. You just need to be sure before you hit the  Enter key on any step. Also, you are right. The 'Bcdedit" command makes GRUB the default and I guess - no way exists which allows you to have grub only on the secondary drive. I have never seen any such guide/link/method that could allow you to do so. 

So, my recommendation would be to stick with this else you might damage your hard disk or any partition in particular.

Comment: alright thanks for the help and clarification