# Dual Booting process stops halfway

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my MSI GP72 7REX laptop aside from Windows 10 as dual boot option.
I allocated some space on my D drive, and made a bootable USB drive.
The process stops halfway. While I am installing Ubuntu(choosing the language, which wifi to connect and so on...), I get a black screen error like the one in the photo [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO5nd.jpg).

I updated BIOS, but it is still not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check the .iso file once. It could be possible that the .iso image file is corrupted. If that's not the case, I would recommend you to check out my answer here >> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125504/proper-way-of-partitioning-a-secondary-hard-drive-for-ubuntu/1125512#1125512

In it, you will also get the understanding of how to install the GRUB menu. 

Hope it helps you.

Comment: See similar: MSi GT72VR-6RE Dominator Pro - some settings required
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365997
Failing to Boot Ubuntu 16.10 in MSI GP72
http://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/failing-to-boot-ubuntu-16-10-in-msi-gp72
[SOLVED] MSI GT72S 6QE - Freezes on boot unless acpi=off is used
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544